# Redirect all requests to https

Tags: nginx

Currently my website doesn't not work if I don't have `https://` in front of the domain `www.mysite.com.au`.

How can I get my nginx config to redirect all http://, mysite.com.au, www.mysite.com.au to https://mysite.com.au. I got the following config from a tutorial:

```
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com.au;

    root /www/mysite.com.au;
    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.au/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.au/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

   location / {
        root /home/farah/;
        index index.html;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did something like this https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

Comment: not working for my setup...

Comment: Can you include the http server code in your question maybe?